# By what factor does Java increase the size of Set / Map, if the size has reached the load factor

Tags: java, collections, hash, hashmap, set

By what factor does Java increase the size of Set / Map, if the size has reached the load factor ? Do we get double size of original Set / Map ?

Comment: It becomes bigger by double length. Please cover my tutorial [Internal life of HashMap](http://volodial.blogspot.com/2013/07/internal-life-of-hashmap-in-java.html) to know hasmap indepth

Comment: @ Volodymyr Wonderful article :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the source code, which comes with the JDK:

```
void addEntry(int hash, K key, V value, int bucketIndex) {
    Entry<K,V> e = table[bucketIndex];
    table[bucketIndex] = new Entry<>(hash, key, value, e);
    if (size++ >= threshold)
        resize(2 * table.length);
}
```

Comment: @ JB Nizet : I am guessing that threshold = initial capacity X load factor

Comment: I could find this post which is also helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139990/what-is-the-load-factor-0-75-mean?rq=1